# Maximum call stack size exceeded in angular 8

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular8

I have 2 dropdown lists. i'm binding product data to it.in one drop with product code and 2nd dropdown with productname. when I select product code from 1st dropdown, second dropdown needs to select productname based on product code. working with one drop down is fine. when written same logic for 2nd dropdown having error

> Maximum call stack size exceeded.

```
 <div class="col-md-9">
 <select id="Code" class="form-control" placeholder="Code"
(ngModelChange)="onCodeChange()" formControlName="sku" required>
 <option [value]="''">Select Code</option>  <option [value]="product.sku"
  *ngFor="let product of productData">   {{product.sku}}
  </option>
 </select>                                                      
  </div>



<div class="col-md-9">
 <select id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"
 (ngModelChange)="onProductChange()" formControlName="productName" required>
  <option [value]="''">Select Name</option>
 <option [value]="product.productName" *ngFor="let product of productData">
 {{product.productName}}
 </option>
</select>
</div>

onCodeChange(): void {
         const stock = (this.sharedService.where(this.productData, 'sku', this.stockForm.controls.sku.value) || {}) as any;
         this.stockForm.controls.productName.reset( stock.productName);

    }
    onProductChange(): void {
        const stock = (this.sharedService.where(this.productData, 'productName', this.stockForm.controls.productName.value) || {}) as any;
        this.stockForm.controls.sku.reset( stock.sku);

    }
```

above productdata contains product related information. here **sku** is product code.

Answer (score 1):

Righty, so my best guess here is you've manged to create yourself an infinite loop.

User selects a `sku` which prompts `ngModelChange` to fire causing the   `onCodeChange()` to be executed.

`onCodeChange` Resets the `productName` control which again causes the `ngModelChange` to fire, but this time for the `product` control `onProductChange`.

`onProductChange` then resets the `sku` thus invoking `onCodeChange`.

This then continues on, and on and on. `onCodeChange` indirectly invoking `onProductChange` and `onProductChange` indirectly invoking `onCodeChange`.

You need to pull the reset code out into a `onselection` event or something similar.

Comment: i changed two way binding to (change) event now working fine. thank u for response garty..

Comment: No problem. Been here myself before.